# Full outer join and count

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I try to recreate the following SQL query in LINQ to return JSON:

```
SELECT a.Title, COUNT(b.ActionID) FROM labels a
FULL JOIN [Values] b ON a.ID = b.ID
GROUP BY a.Title
```

I tried:

```
public ActionResult Json()
{

    IEnumerable < object > query = (from a in db.Labels
                                    join b in db.Values on a.ID equals b.ID  
                                    group b.ID by a.Title into grp
                                    select new
                                    {
                                        Label = grp.Key,
                                        Value = grp.Count()

                                 }).ToList();

    return Json(query, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

The Result returns only labels that have a value:

```
[{"Label":"New","Value":2}]
```

But what I need is:

```
[
{"Label":"A","Value":2},
{"Label":"B","Value":0},
{"Label":"C","Value":0},
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just do this:

```
IEnumerable < object > query = (from a in db.Labels
                                select new
                                {
                                    Label = a.Title,
                                    Value = db.Values
                                              .Where(w=>w.ID==a.ID)
                                              .Count()
                                 }).ToList();
```